# Java serversocket control synchronization issue

Tags: java, controls, serversocket

I'm working with some java to create a small client to monitor a network. For each node on the network, I am running a client, but also a ServerSocket to listen for incoming connections. The code I have written seems to be hanging up on the ServerSocket.listen() method. I am trying to run some test code that needs to start the server socket, and after it's set up, send it some data. Essentially my problem looks like this:

Client.java

```
/*snip*/
public void listen(){
    try{
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
        server.listen();
        Socket client = server.accept()
        System.out.println("got connection");
        ... do stuff
    catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

TestClient.java

```
/*snip*/
Client client = new Client();
client.listen();
System.out.println("client constructed, waiting for connection");
Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
... do stuff
```

Every other example of java ServerSocket places it in its own class just to loop over itself and run in an infinite loop. I'm trying to make the server execute from another main method if possible. The problem, from what I can tell, is that the client.listen() method never completes because the socket never acquires its connection. I try to establish the connection after that line of code executes in the TestClient: in eclipse, neither of the println's get printed to the output. Is there another way to write the control structure to handle this in a clever way?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Your client is in fact a server, and it blocks until a connection is received. So nothing will be executed after the call to `server.accept()`, unless you connect, from another thread or another process, to this server socket.

Comment: What I am trying to do is avoid having a class that I have to execute separately to listen for connections. Unfortunately, I haven't seen any java programs where I didn't have to execute the server in one program, then send it data using another. I'd like to be able to do both from one test program. In other words, I'd like the client to somehow gloss over the listen() method even though it doesn't yet have a connection.

Comment: Then implement the client in another thread of the same test application.

Comment: I'm still not certain how that would look. In this test program I will have some kind of startserver(); then startclient() ? I don't see how it would still pass beyond the point where the server waits for an incoming connection before finishing the method.

Comment: Start the client thread before starting the server, or start both the server and the client in two different threads. Or only start the server in a different thread and leave the client in the main thread.

Comment: "The code I have written seems to be hanging up on the ServerSocket.listen() method." There is no such method.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this? You can have the server socket run in a separate thread

```
package test;

import java.net.*;

public class Clerver {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private int listenPort;
    private Thread listenerThread;

    public Clerver(int listenPort) {
        this.listenPort = listenPort;
    }

    public void runIt() throws Exception {

        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(listenPort);
        this.listenerThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (Clerver.this) {
                    Clerver.this.notify();
                }
                try {
                    Socket clientSocket = Clerver.this.serverSocket.accept();
                    receiveDataOnServer(clientSocket);
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        this.listenerThread.start();
        synchronized (this) {
            this.wait();
        }
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", listenPort);
        sendDataFromClient(sock);
        receiveDataFromServer(sock);
        System.out.println(">> All done!");
        listenerThread.join();
        System.out.println(">> Bye Bye!");
    }

    private void sendDataFromClient(Socket sock) throws Exception {
        sock.getOutputStream().write("Hello".getBytes());
        System.out.println(">> Sent HELLO");
    }

    private void receiveDataFromServer(Socket sock) throws Exception {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int bread = sock.getInputStream().read(buf);
        String response = new String(buf, 0, bread);
        System.out.println("<< RESPONSE from SERVER: " + response);
    }

    private void receiveDataOnServer(Socket sock) throws Exception {

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int bread = sock.getInputStream().read(buf);
        String response = new String(buf, 0, bread);
        System.out.println(">> Received on Server : " + response);
        sock.getOutputStream().write("WORLD".getBytes());
        System.out.println(">> SERVER sent response back");
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Clerver c = new Clerver(1234);
        c.runIt();

    }

}
```

Comment: This worked very well, thank you for the help. I have a lot more to learn about multithreading and how to implement threads. You've given me a good opportunity to learn more.